# Qual é o critério para perguntas na aba "interessante"

Tags: debate

Na homepage do SOpt tem as seguintes abas: ativas, destaque, interessante, semana, mês.

Entrei na aba interessante, e não consegui identificar um padrão nas perguntas. Tem pergunta com tag favorita minha, umas com coisa que nunca respondi, perguntas com votos e sem votos.

Qual é filtro utilizado nessa aba?

Comment: Disfarça, tinha um tooltip, não tinha visto!

Comment: Não tinha visto que tinha um tooltip ao parar o mouse no link: "Perguntas com a maioria das visualizações, respostas e votos nos últimos dias".

Mas de qualquer forma ainda achei estranho, jamais iria achar isso, pois tem bastante pergunta com pouca visualização e sem voto. Considerem fechar a questão se for o caso.

Comment: Você pode transformar seu comentário em resposta `;)`